# NHibernate Exception Occurred getter of Id; Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am struggling with mapping subclasses using NHibernate.  I am saving reports that we generate and currently there are **two different criteria types** that I am serializing and would like to store in one column (Criteria) per report: **Basic** and **Time**.  Every report will have an XML column for criteria that is not null.  Here are my classes:

My **Report** class is the primary class being mapped:

```
namespace Core {
    public class Report {
        public virtual int ReportId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ReportCriteria Criteria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My **ReportCriteria** class is abstract and inherited by the two criteria types:

```
namespace Core{
    [XmlRoot("Criteria"), Serializable]
    public abstract class ReportCriteria {
        public abstract string GenSql();
    }
}
```

My **BasicCriteria** class inherits from ReportCriteria and uses the GenSql() method:

```
namespace Core {
    [XmlRoot("Criteria"), Serializable]
    public class BasicCriteria : ReportCriteria {
        public override string GenSql(){
            //method implementation
        }
    }    
}
```

My **TimeCriteria** class inherits from ReportCriteria and uses the GenSql() method:

```
namespace Core {
    [XmlRoot("Criteria"), Serializable]
    public class TimeCriteria : ReportCriteria {
        [Past]
        public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public override string GenSql(){
            //method implementation
        }
    }    
}
```

Finally, my mapping file (**Report.hbm.xml)** is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="Core" assembly="Core" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Report" table="Report">
        <id name="ReportId">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="CriteriaType" />
        <property name="Name" />
        <subclass name="Core.BasicCriteria" discriminator-value="Basic">
            <property name="Criteria" type="Data.NHibernate.XmlSerializableType`1[[Core.BasicCriteria, Core]], Data" />
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="Core.TimeCriteria" discriminator-value="Time">
            <property name="Criteria" type="Data.NHibernate.XmlSerializableType`1[[Core.TimeCriteria, Core]], Data" />
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Data.NHibernate.XmlSerializableType is a class which accepts generic types and serializes them for data persistence.

Please help me figure out what is wrong with my mapping which is causing the following error to occur:
Ex: ***Exception occurred getter of Core.Report.ReportId*** 
Inner: ***Object does not match target type.***

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<id name="ReportId" type="Int32">
```

NHibernate attempts to resolve as string by default so you need to tell it that it is an integer.

**Update**

Your basic issue is that you are trying to say in your mapping that BasicCriteria and TimeCriteria are subclasses of Report which is not the case. You need to reconsider your mapping strategy. It's been a while since I've done something like this but what you are hinting at (with your criteria columns in the Report table) is a polymorphic component relationship which is not supported. You may want to look a UserTypes

Comment: Thanks, but I actually have that in my current code and am still getting the same error.  Apologies: I stripped that detail out of my above code to ease reading.  The issue is definitely pointing towards my subclasses.  Everything works until I try to map those.

Comment: Also, I am specifying type="String" for my discriminator.

Comment: Thanks - I was being stupid to try and hack it and my model still needed some work.  I used an XmlSerializableUserType another guy I work with wrote to map the one "Criteria" property.  Also, I had to remove abstract from ReportCriteria.  My final mapping was:  
        <property name="Criteria" type="Data.NHibernate.XmlSerializableType`1[Core.ReportCriteria, Core], Data" />

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because the condition for retrieving the entity via NH's linq provider included calling IEnumerable's Contains extension method when it was not IQueryable instance. Turning the collection into List by ToList() solved it because ICollection has native support for Contains().